# How can I create a mongoose schema for a Questionnaire app like google forms in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am creating an application in nodejs, where I want the user to create his own text field similar to the one in google forms where for instance, I create the first field as name, next field as age also a text field and the third as dropdown for gender to also hold the title as well as the drop down options.

My Question is How can I structure the mongoose database schema to hold these information. Storing the field names and the input when given.

Also How can I perform that for the dropdown.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const questionaireSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Name is required'],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Email is required'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please enter a valid email'],
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Phone is required'],
    unique: true,
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ["male", "female", "prefer not to say"]
  }
})

const Questionnaire = mongoose.model('Questionnaire', questionaireSchema)
module.exports = Questionnaire
```

Instead of the above, I want the author to be able to provide his needed input fields which can be different from another author's input field. Help someone.

I hope i explained it properly.

Comment: I think you can use a field with data type array. So that user can store his own key/value [data types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/)

Answer (score 0):

Add following filed in `questionaireSchema`

```
formData: [{
label : String,
value : String
}]
```

Now save all the dynamic form data in `formData` field from req.body.formData

Ex.of req.body.formData

```
[
    {
        label: "name",
        value : "XYZ"
    },
     {
        label: "email",
        value : "XYZ@mail.com"
    },

]
```